# what have gcc done when I try to make a array overflow?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I tried a piece of code which made a array overflow,but something unexpected happened when I compiled it with gcc. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int a[] = {0,2,4,7};
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    int i;
    printf("%d, %X\n", size, &a);
    a[4] = 6;
    printf("%d, %X\n", size, &a);
    a[5] = 78;
    printf("%d, %X\n", size, &a);
    a[6] = 65;
    printf("%d, %X\n", size, &a);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a[size], a[size+1], a[size+2]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is:

```
4, BFC4DDF8
6, BFC4DDF8
6, BFC4DDF8
6, BFC4DDF8
0, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 65, 0, 0
```

So in the code, I did not change the value of size, but when it ran, it did change by itself! So can anyone tell me why this happen?

PS: gcc version is 4.8.0.

According to @NPE answer, and I check the address of `size` and it actually be located in memory right after `a`.

But when I add a piece of code

```
printf("%X\n", &size);
```

before

```
printf("%d, %X\n", size, &a);
```

the result is

```
BFC39108
4, BFC3910C
4, BFC3910C
4, BFC3910C
4, BFC3910C
0, 2, 4, 7, 4, 78, 65
```

at this time, `size` is located in memory right before `a`.

---

In fact, wherever I print `size`'s address, it is located just right before `a`'s address; and if I don't print `size`'s address, it is located just right after `a`'s address.So is it still the compiler's undefined behavior?

Comment: I expected the value of size should not change.

Comment: You can no longer expect that once you've got undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you write past the end of `a`, your program has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that it can behave in any way it pleases, including in the way you're observing.

What's happening in practice is that `size` happens to be located in memory right after `a`, and the following out-of-bounds assignment:

```
a[4] = 6;
```

overwrites `size`.

Note that the code can fail in some other way if you use a different compiler or different compiler settings, or make seemingly inconsequential changes to the program. Or it could work well throughout your testing, and then blow up in your customer's face.

Comment: But it seems that `size` is located in memeory right after `a` every time when it runs.

Comment: @Jude: Computers are fairly predictable in that, if you give them the same instructions, they would do the same thing. Therefore you should not be surprised. The behaviour is still undefined, and tomorrow `size` might not be located right after `a`.

Comment: I have just edited the question, and if I print `size`'s address at any places, it is just located right before `a`'s address. So is this still compiler's easter egg?

Answer (score 0):

You overwrote memory past the end of the a[] array, and therefore overwrote the value of size.